# Animated gif created with ImageMagick has glitchy block color background

Tags: imagemagick, png, gif, animated-gif, imagemagick-convert

I am trying to stitch together a bunch of .png's which contain some alpha (transparency) but which have a uniformly white background. The png's look fine individually, but in the resulting .gif some frames acquire a patchy background that appears to have the same RGBA color as some of the points being animated.

[image: example of glitchy behavior]

I have tried the following commands

```
convert -delay 1 im*.png anim.gif
convert -delay 1 -alpha set im*.png anim.gif
convert -delay 1 -alpha set -dispose background im*.png anim.gif
convert -delay 1 -alpha set -dispose previous im*.png anim.gif
convert -delay 1 -alpha set -dispose previous -background white im*.png anim.gif
```

pretty much just trying additional flags to see if anything happens to fix the glitch, but I get the same behavior in every case. Anyone have a fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34168718/imagemagick-gif-overlay-preserves-alpha-on-background?rq=1) led me to the right answer --

```
convert -delay 1 -layers Optimize im*.png anim.gif
```

works!